# How can I show a value from SELECT ... GROUP BY as a card in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, card

I have Power BI Desktop, and my source is Direct SQL Server; and I need PBI to query database every time it is used. Below is my code:

```
SELECT [ShippingStatus], COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [ShippingStatus]
--Shipping Status values: Shipped, Processing, Awaiting, Queued

Values returned are: 
Shipped: 10
Processing: 5
Awaiting: 2
Queued: 1
```

I need each of these statuses to show up as a card (this is a must). But the only thing that works is a card-row. But I need them to appear as single cards with just one number and a title beneath it. Like this:

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to define multiple measures, you can create a single multi-row card with the shipping status and row count that looks something like one of these depending on the formatting you choose:

[image: Visual]
[image: Visual2]

It's not exactly what you were asking for but might be close enough.

Comment: I like this approach, thank you. is there any way to make it horizontal?

Comment: There's not a built-in multi-column card but you might get an approximation with the matrix visual.

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure like these:

```
Shipped Count = COUNTX(FILTER(myTable, [ShippingStatus]="Shipped"),[ShippingStatus])
Processing Count = COUNTX(FILTER(myTable, [ShippingStatus]="Processing"),[ShippingStatus])
Awaiting Count = COUNTX(FILTER(myTable, [ShippingStatus]="Awaiting"),[ShippingStatus])
Queued Count = COUNTX(FILTER(myTable, [ShippingStatus]="Queued"),[ShippingStatus])
```

[image]

---

If you don't want to create measures, you can use another type of visualization.

Matrix:

[image]

Multi-row card:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am new to PBI, so the only way to achieve this is really by creating new measures? Thanks again

Comment: It's the Power BI way. You want 4 cards, so they all need some kind of query. Creating a measure seems like a straight-forward way in Power BI.

Comment: I muse use the cards, but thank you very much for your answer. I will select it as resolved.

Comment: Actually, this returns an incorrect result. This is counting the number of values, which is always one. My query returns Status alongside its count

Comment: I think it deserves a separate question